# Can I apply a template to a object-variable of a ngFor - loop in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a app-projects template which is a list of `ProjectComponent`. 
For `ProjectComponent`. I have the app-project template.

```html
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let project of projects">
  <app-project></app-project> 
</li>
</ul>
```

Component:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'app-project',
  templateUrl: './project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project.component.css']
})
export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(title: string, description: string, questions: string[]) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

So, now I want to iterate over the the individual projectComponents while applying their templates.

But I could not figure out how to do that: If I want to stick with the separate template I somehow would have to pass the item to the template.

I found that it would be possible for single properties via Inputs, but that does not help me much with this.

Comment: Component constructors are used for DI, not to pass data. That's what Inputs, Services etc are for.

Comment: sounds reasonable, but how would apply the templates for the objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get the `project` into your `ProjectComponent` as input property using `@Input()` to do that.

You could use like bellow:

ProjectComponent:

```typescript
export class ProjectComponent {

  @Input() project;

  constructor() { }

}
```

In the template you are using `<app-project>` you need to input that `project` property into `ProjectComponent` like bellow:

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let project of projects">
        <app-project [project]=project></app-project>
    </li>
</ul>
```

<kbd>[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c2oh3l?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)</kbd>

Hope this will help you!

Comment: thanks for your answer, but would it not be kind of redundant to have the ProjectComponent and then the actual class as a property? In other words, would it not be better to have the properties of project directly in ProjectComponent?

Comment: in Angular only way to input your `project` into `<app-project>` like this. this is the standard way to do that. I don't think you could do it like you think. it is not the better way to do that even. but you could defined `Project` modal in one place and you could use it that would be better I think

Comment: "but you could defined Project modal in one place and you could use it that would be better I think" could you elaborate on that, please? Did not fully understand it

Comment: also in Component `constructor` use to inject services. I mean `title: string, description: string, questions: string[]`  take these things to separate modal if you prefer

Comment: Indeed, I use a service for projectSComponent (via DI). But I do not know how it could make sense to use a service here, too...

Comment: I updated my [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c2oh3l?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) hope you could get an idea from it.